# DataAnnotation and value by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, data-annotations

I have a property in view model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
```

and view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and page shows default value as 01/01/0001 on form:

[image]

I want have not any default value (user should specify correct value and can't send form without it). How to remove default value?

Comment: Make the property `DateTime?` (nullable), add the`[Required]` attribute and change the format to `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (the HTML-5 browser requires ISO format, which is then displayed in the browsers format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make public `System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }` a **nullable** `DateTime`.